# displaying data from the database

Tags: php, sql

am trying this web based dictionary for learning, but i am having some problem regarding fetching the result from database and displaying the words. its showing an error message as  "mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Dictionary\home.php on line 14"
below is the code..please help

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dictionary");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
<table>
<?php
$result=mysql_query("select word from word_table order by asc");
//$row = mysql_query($result);
while($word = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo("<tr><td>$word[0]</td></tr>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it mysql or mysqli!?

Comment: you didn't put a column name for your order by. Try this query" select word from word_table order by word asc

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `mysqli` here, because you used `mysqli` dor DB connection

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select word from word_table order by asc");

while($word = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
```

Also `mysqli_connect` takes 4 parameter for DB connection

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dictionary","your_password","db_name");
```

**Edit**

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select word from word_table order by column_name asc");
```

Comment: thanks a lot but is it necessary to give the directory and password...coz without that also its running fine with other pages.

Comment: @user2446626 Yes it is necessary to give `username,password,db_name`. See edited answer also. And accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: still its showing "mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Dictionary\home.php on line 14" i don't know what's going wrong...:(